# Preferred way to connect to Immutant Message Queuing service from eg C# application

Tags: clojure, hornetq, immutant

Title does not include this constraint: the Broker needs to be embedded.

With straight HornetQ I would just use StompConnect to expose the service to the outside world and that would allow .NET clients to connect pretty easily.  There's also the possibility of websockets and REST now.

What is the preferred method?